# Marketing Cloud Connect - Editing Synchronization Settings fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

When trying to edit synchronized data sources - especially the filter that determines which records should be synced to Marketing Cloud - I currently receive the following error message:

> "An error occurred attempting to retrieve Synchronization Settings. Try again later."

[image: Configure Synchronization Interface]

Therefore the filter cannot be adjusted at this time.

This is the documentation related to this function: [Edit Synchronization Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_edit_synchronization_settings.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is a front end (user interface) bug that prevents the setting change to be performed successfully.

In order for the interface to work correctly every form field needs to be clicked and edited before setting it to the desired value. This also applies if the correct value already is selected on load of the dialog.

Answer of the Salesforce support engineer:

> "while making any changes you need to select all fields manually and then have to click on save"